# Unable to send Email using nodemailer in protractor.conf.js onComplete: function()

Tags: protractor

Unable to send Email using nodemailer in protractor.conf.js onComplete: function(). Used the below code and it does not execute onComplete block

```
onComplete: function() {    
    var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true, // use SSL
        auth: {
            user: 'email',
            pass: 'password'
        }
    });
    var mailOptions = {
            from: '"TestMail" <>', // sender address (who sends)
            to: 'receiver's email', // list of receivers (who receives)
            subject: 'Hello through conf', // Subject line
            text: 'Hello world ', // plaintext body
            html: '<b>Hello world </b><br> This is the first email sent with Nodemailer in Node.js', // html body


    };

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
            if(error){
                return console.log(error);
            }

            console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a Promise. Only then `onComplete()` would wait till the Promise is resolved - mail is triggered.

> A callback function called once tests are finished. onComplete can
>   optionally return a promise, which Protractor will wait for before
>   shutting down webdriver.
>         At this point, tests will be done but global objects will still be    available.
>   `onComplete?: () => void`

You need to convert your function to return a Promise once an email is trigerred successfully. Refer this [beautiful tutorial](https://www.promisejs.org/). They have a very good example on converting a `fs.readFile()` to return a promise

You can do something like this.

```
onComplete: function() {
    return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
            port: 465,
            secure: true, // use SSL
            auth: {
                user: 'email',
                pass: 'password'
            }
        });
        var mailOptions = {
            from: '"TestMail" <>', // sender address (who sends)
            to: 'receiver's email', // list of receivers (who receives)
            subject: 'Hello through conf', // Subject line
            text: 'Hello world ', // plaintext body
            html: '<b>Hello world </b><br> This is the first email sent with Nodemailer in Node.js', // html body
    };
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
            if(error){
                reject(err);
            }
            fulfill(info);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: above code is not working, i have used as it is code and after execution email is not getting triggered, browser remains open so looks iike promise is not getting resolved , it is not showing any error on console